# reading file large file very slow, please help

Tags: regex, vb.net, winforms, file-io, structure

this code takes about 30 mins and high cpu usage, what is the problem

```
Do
  strLine = objReader.ReadLine()
  If strLine Is Nothing Then
    Exit Do
  End If
  'check valid proxy
  m = Regex.Match(strLine.Trim, strProxyParttern)
  strMatch = m.Value.Trim
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strMatch) = True OrElse _
    strMatch.Contains("..") = True Then
    Continue Do
  End If
  ' create proxy
  With tmpProxy
    .IP = strMatch.Substring(0, strMatch.IndexOf(":"))
    .Port = CInt(strMatch.Substring(strMatch.IndexOf(":") + 1))
    .Status = "new"
  End With
  ' check 
  If lstProxys.Contains(tmpProxy) = True Then
    Continue Do
  End If
  lstProxys.Add(tmpProxy)
  Debug.Print(lstProxys.Count.ToString)
Loop Until strLine Is Nothing
If lstProxys.Count < 1 Then
  Exit Sub
End If
```

is the slowness from the comparism or from reading the file or from the regex?

**EDIT**

profiling the code like this

```
 Dim myTimer As New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
        Dim t1 As Integer = 0
        Dim t2 As Integer = 0
        Dim t3 As Integer = 0
        'read the file line by line, collecting valid proxy
        Do
            'Read a line fromn the file
            myTimer.Reset()
            myTimer.Start()
            strLine = objReader.ReadLine()
            If strLine Is Nothing Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            myTimer.Stop()
            t1 = myTimer.Elapsed.Milliseconds
            'check valid proxy
            myTimer.Reset()
            myTimer.Start()
            m = Regex.Match(strLine.Trim, strProxyParttern)
            strMatch = m.Value.Trim
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strMatch) = True OrElse _
                strMatch.Contains("..") = True Then
                Continue Do
            End If
            myTimer.Stop()
            t2 = myTimer.Elapsed.Milliseconds
            ' create proxy
            myTimer.Reset()
            myTimer.Start()
            tmpProxy.IP = strMatch.Substring(0, strMatch.IndexOf(":"))
            tmpProxy.Port = CInt(strMatch.Substring(strMatch.IndexOf(":") + 1))
            tmpProxy.Status = "new"

            ' check 
            If lstProxys.Contains(tmpProxy) = True Then
                Continue Do
            End If
            lstProxys.Add(tmpProxy)
            myTimer.Stop()
            t2 = myTimer.Elapsed.Milliseconds
            Debug.Print(String.Format("Read={0}, Match={1}, Add={2}", t1, t2, t3))
        Loop Until strLine Is Nothing
```

gave these results

```
Read=0, Match=0, Add=1
Read=0, Match=0, Add=1
Read=0, Match=0, Add=2
...
Read=0, Match=0, Add=9
Read=0, Match=0, Add=9
Read=0, Match=0, Add=10
...
...
Read=0, Match=0, Add=39
Read=0, Match=0, Add=39
Read=0, Match=0, Add=40
etc
```

looks like the code is ok right, except for the add to the list

Comment: How big is this file? 30 minutes for 1 line is long. 30 minutes for 10 billion lines is fast.

Comment: What's `strProxyPattern`? It is very easy to create a regex that will take an *extremely* long time to complete (with the kind of regex engine .NET uses). Also, have you (or some other component you're using) set `Regex.CacheSize`?

Comment: strProxyParttern As String = "[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[:][0-9]{1,5}"

Comment: lstProxys.Contains will take a long time for a large file. You should use a dictionary or check for duplicates in another routine.

Comment: @Marc  the file is just 90,000 lines

Comment: @Meta-Knight: As the list never gets any larger than one item, it will be fast to seek through it...

Comment: @Meta-Knight do you have any routine foe looking for duplicates in `list<of structure>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed issue is because you are using a List(Of Structure).  The List.Contains method is a linear search (it goes through each item of the list to see if it matches) so it takes increasingly longer the more unique items you add to the list.

Because you're dealing with a large number of items, change lstProxys into a HashSet(Of T).  You should see a huge performance boost.  All you should need to do is change the definition of lstProxys:

```
Dim lstProxys as New HashSet(Of structure)
```

Comment: thanks, but i cant use `hashset` in .net 2.0, any solution to this?

Comment: If you install the .net 3.5 framework on your computer you can add a reference to System.Core.  Since the .net frameworks versions 2.0 - 3.5 all share the same CLR you can use the assembly in your 2.0 application.  To distribute the app, you'd need to make sure the user has .net 3.5 framework installed, or you'd need to include the System.Core.dll with the application

Comment: ok, thanks, but can i include only reference to the system.core.dll and target .net 2.0 framework?

Comment: Yes, you can only include the reference to System.Core and still target the .net 2.0 framework.  However if any of your end users are on windows 2000 it will not work since .net 3.5 is not compatible with win2k

Comment: so my app only needs .net 2.0 installed and the system.core.dll, will this work without .net 3.0 installed, that is what am asking. thanks again

Comment: Your computer needs to have .net 3.5 installed in order to get a reference to system.core.dll. The computers you are installing the software on only need .net 2.0; but if they are running windows 2000 then system.core.dll will not work.

Answer (score 1):

> is the slowness from the comparism or from reading the file or from the regex?

We could take educated guesses but why not measure it instead.

For example run the following three tests separately under release mode and without the debugger attached and see how long it takes

```
'Test 1 Just IO

Do
  strLine = objReader.ReadLine()

Loop Until strLine Is Nothing
If lstProxys.Count < 1 Then
  Exit Sub
End If

'Test 2 IO + Regex

Do
  strLine = objReader.ReadLine()
  If strLine Is Nothing Then
    Exit Do
  End If
  'check valid proxy
  m = Regex.Match(strLine.Trim, strProxyParttern)
  strMatch = m.Value.Trim
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strMatch) = True OrElse _
    strMatch.Contains("..") = True Then
    Continue Do
  End If

Loop Until strLine Is Nothing
If lstProxys.Count < 1 Then
  Exit Sub
End If

'Test 3 IO + regex and Compare
Do
  strLine = objReader.ReadLine()
  If strLine Is Nothing Then
    Exit Do
  End If
  'check valid proxy
  m = Regex.Match(strLine.Trim, strProxyParttern)
  strMatch = m.Value.Trim
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strMatch) = True OrElse _
    strMatch.Contains("..") = True Then
    Continue Do
  End If
  ' create proxy
  With tmpProxy
    .IP = strMatch.Substring(0, strMatch.IndexOf(":"))
    .Port = CInt(strMatch.Substring(strMatch.IndexOf(":") + 1))
    .Status = "new"
  End With
  ' check 
  If lstProxys.Contains(tmpProxy) = True Then
    Continue Do
  End If
  lstProxys.Add(tmpProxy)
  Debug.Print(lstProxys.Count.ToString)
Loop Until strLine Is Nothing
If lstProxys.Count < 1 Then
  Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

The disk I/O is usually the limiting factor for something like this. Depending on the disk speed you could expect a throughput of about 5-20 megabyte per second.

Regular expressions can be slow if they contain expressions that cause a lot of backtracking, so that is a possibility, but it should be pretty bad to be noticable compared to the disk I/O.

As there will never be more than one item in the proxy list, that comparion can't be the problem. You are not creating any new proxy object, but reusing the same, which means that you change the property of the object that you have already put in the list. As you are comparing the object with itself, the list will always contain the object after the first iteration, and will never be added a second time.

Does the proxy class do anything when you assign values to its properties? If it does something like creating a connection, that might be what's taking so long.

Comment: actually, its a proxy structure, it does do anything at this code, just need to get unique proxy, so this method. will using a dictionary (of structure) suffice

Comment: @Smith: So it's a struct, not a class? Then you don't have the problem that I described, but you have a struct that is mutable, which is generally considered to be bad practice.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by a mutable struct?

Comment: @Smith: A mutable struct is one where you can change the properties, so it works as a class in that respect, but as a struct in others. The compiler warns about some cases when this causes problems, but not all.